# Display a welcome message using the application_start event handler in global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net

I simply want to have a message pop up when the application starts. I have tried this but it is not working

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>

    <script Language="C#" runat="server">

      void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            // Code that runs on application startup
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<hr/>Welcome to our final project this is an example of an event handler");

        }
```

It doesn't return an error but it also doesn't display the message I have written, Is there anyway to use `MessageBox.show` or something similar to accomplish this?

Comment: Where would you expect the message to appear? This code runs on the server, and does not have a window to display in. FYI, `Application_Start` doesn't fire the first time each user accesses the application. It fires the first time _any_ user accesses the application. Only once.

Comment: @JohnSaunders So how can I make it display in a page or better yet make it a pop up dialog box that displays my message

Comment: You can't. You have to do that in the web application. Most likely, you want to use Forms Authentication, and when the user is not logged in, you want to direct them to a login page. Once they've logged in, maybe you want do display a message on the home page, or maybe somewhere else. I suspect that you don't know much about web development.

Comment: @johnSaunders no these event handlers are completely new to me. But thank you I'll figure something out

Comment: @johnSaunders Figured out a way to make this work using your comments as guidance thank you!

Comment: You'll thank me better by posting your solution as an answer to this question. You can even make it the accepted answer and get points for it.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have achieved this is:

In my Global.asax file I have declared a session start variable and set it as an App variable as follows

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var counter = 1;
        HttpContext.Current.Application["Counter"] = counter;
    }
```

In my default.aspx file I have an onload() function for the body which brings up a modal with my message, only if App.Counter = 1, then change it to 2 as follows

```
@if (App.Counter == 1){<text>onload="modal()"</text>; App.SessionStart = 2;}
```

Alternatively instead of an onload function you could use

```
@if (App.Counter == 1){
    <p>Your welcome message here!</p>
    App.SessionStart = 2;
}
```